# Scripted way to add nuget package source

Tags: nuget

We want to start a company nuget package repository.
Is there a way to add a package source through command line so we can configure our new package source through a setup or something?

We basically don't want to go

> Tools - Options - Package Manager - Package Sources - Plus button -
>   add name and source

on every developer machine in the company.

Comment: Haven't found it yet, would like it too

Comment: As an idea........if you run a nuget.exe from the powershell window in VS.......and override the (Sources (?)) (going from memory), I wonder if it remembers it?  Probably not, but maybe worth a try.  As in, the command-line version of nuget.........

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The package sources are stored in NuGet.config under the user's profile or system wide in ProgramData:

```
%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config
%ProgramData%\NuGet\NuGetDefaults.config
```

You can add package sources through NuGet using a command line similar to:

```
nuget sources add -name FeedName -Source http://YourFeed.com
```

The above command will work if you run it under the user's profile.

NuGet 2.7 introduced [system wide package source configuration](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-defaults) in ProgramData. So you could add your package sources into NuGet.config under ProgramData with your installer.

Comment: Putting that `nuget sources add ...` in an auto-ci script is OK, as it is just a warning to add the exact same source twice.  That way, it doesn't matter which virtual CI system you are running on, the list gets updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dotnet CLI to add a new source with following command:

```
dotnet nuget add source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/Owner/index.json" --name "Source1" --username "test@mail.com" --password "pass"
```