# How to specify source for dependent package when installing package from nuget cli?

Tags: c#, nuget

My c# project was referring to a package Pkg-Ori from source nuget.org.
Then I tried to download the source code of this package, modified it, packed and pushed to my own nuget source as Pkg-Modified for some reason.

Then another package Pkg-A referred to Pkg-Modified(on my own source) and Newtonsoft.Json(on source nuget.org).

When I install Pkg-A using nuget cli with source of my own source, Pkg-Ori on source nuget.org is installed instead of Pkg-Modified on my own source.

How can I tell nuget cli to install Pkg-Modified from my own source?

Or is there any better practice to use a modifed package from nuget.org, or do I need to change the namespace and package id?

Comment: Is this your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001158/scripted-way-to-add-nuget-package-source

Comment: @MahanLameie, it is a different question from mine, about how to add additional source.

Comment: There seems no way to specify source for the dependencoes only. One try is to install the dependency first with its source, then install the package you really want. It seems nuget will only check if the package is installed but has no idea where is the package from.